# How Does Java Handle Throwaway Values

Tags: java, arraylist, semantics

My AP Computer Science textbook states that the `add()` method in the `List` interface always returns `true`, yet when this method is called, its return type does not have to be assigned.

[image]

I assume the value is just thrown away because it is not assigned to anything in this situation. This begs the question, **in which situations are values "thrown away".** For example, the following does not compile.

[image]

Why does the second snippet not compile when it is essentially *leaving behind* the same value as the first snippet? (`list.add()` returns `true`, `(1 < 2)` yields `true`).

Comment: One's a method return value. The other is not a statement.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Yes, but they both result in a truthy value, in both cases `true`.

Comment: no, you'd get a compile error if you just put `false;` or `true;` on a line of code.

Comment: Yes, but `true;` by itself is not a statement. `boolean throwaway() {return 1 < 2; }` is.

Comment: For future questions, it is often better to copy&paste source code into your questions, as opposed to images of source code.

Comment: They collect in the bit bucket, and every so often you have to empty it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return values can be ignored. Incomplete expressions are still incomplete. You could assign it to a variable (and never reference it again) - that would "throw away" the value (eclipse will warn you, but it's not an error) -

```
// This is legal, note that a is never referenced after assignment.
public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean a = (1 < 2);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Blocks of code can contain statements, but not expressions by themselves.  [Section 14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) defines what can be inside blocks, and expressions by themselves are not allowed.

> Block:
>
> - { [BlockStatements] }
>
> BlockStatements:
>
> - BlockStatement {BlockStatement}
>
> BlockStatement:
>
> - LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
> - ClassDeclaration
> - **Statement**

(emphasis mine)

One possible statement is a method invocation, so a method invocation whose return value isn't assigned is a statement, but the expression by itself is not a statement.

[Section 14.5 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) defines a statement as one of the following:

> Statement:
>   - StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>
> - LabeledStatement
> - IfThenStatement
> - IfThenElseStatement
> - WhileStatement
> - ForStatement
>
> StatementNoShortIf:
>
> - StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
> - LabeledStatementNoShortIf
> - IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf
> - WhileStatementNoShortIf
> - ForStatementNoShortIf
>
> StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
>
> - Block
> - EmptyStatement
> - **ExpressionStatement**
> - AssertStatement
> - SwitchStatement
> - DoStatement
> - BreakStatement
> - ContinueStatement
> - ReturnStatement
> - SynchronizedStatement
> - ThrowStatement
> - TryStatement

(emphasis mine)

[Section 14.8 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) defines an "expression statement":

> ExpressionStatement:
>
> - StatementExpression ;
> - StatementExpression:
> - Assignment
> - PreIncrementExpression
> - PreDecrementExpression
> - PostIncrementExpression
> - PostDecrementExpression
> - **MethodInvocation**
> - ClassInstanceCreationExpression

(emphasis mine)

An expression by itself is not an expression statement or a statement.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Calling a method that returns a value has a meaning, because it is not just that return value. In given example method is adding item to a collection and returns it reference, so it can be further handled.

Second example is giving you an error, because without assigning its result to a variable its meaningless. its even worse than `dead code`.

Theoretically, second statement could not be a bug, but why on earth anyone would want to write such "statements"?

Expressions, that literally gives anything is just a processor consumer, an error, and should not be used in any program **period**.

```
(1<2);
```

could be easy translated to a bytecode, and afther that to a processor instructions such as

```
PUSH EAX;
PUSH EBX;
PUSHF;
MOV EAX, 1;
MOV EBX, 2;
CMP EAX,EBX;
POPF;
POP EBX;
POP EAX;
```

or even simpler

```
PUSHF;
CMP 1,2;
POPF;
```

Only thing that code above will change is increasing register pointing to a next code in memory (and few other). So why would anyone would execute such lines?

Comment: -1 Your answer is confusing. The last statement especially: "Code, that literally gives anything is just a processor consumer, an error, and should not be used in any program period." seems like nonsense.

Comment: You're probably right, i just tried to point out, that such expressions is not treated as a statements, because executing it will not affect a program except delay it's finishing. Expressions like (2>5) or (1+1) without result assignment could be easy translated to a processor instructions. But trying to use such instructions is pointless, that why it is treated as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Generated compilation error is related to java grammer. Java grammer states that body of a java function consists sequence of statements. According to this grammer statement can be any assignment,method call,conditional structure, loops, etc. But a < b is a logical expression which can not be assumed as an statement. So this is about the difference between expression and statement not throwning values away.